# cmake --build vs make, what the difference?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, makefile, gnu-make

After

```
cd build
cmake -B . -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=~/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake -S ..
```

Looks like

```
cmake --build .
```

and

```
make
```

do the same here on macOS.

So, when should I use one or the other?

Comment: According to the cmake documentation: `Alternatively, one may use cmake to Build a Project by automatically choosing and invoking the appropriate native build tool.`. So I guess if your project used ninja or something other than make, you could have cmake figure out which commands to invoke to build your project.

Comment: No difference except if another generator is used, then `make` will fail.

Comment: If you're scripting your build system, just use `cmake --build bldloc`. When you move your project to another platform wiht alternate generator(s) you'll be glad you did it. Btw, I use a mac as well, and cmake + vscode + lldb, cmake, and c++ extensions = much love. Strongly recc.

Answer (score 11):

For a simple use there is not much difference, except that `cmake --build` is more generic and works with any generator. So today you use `make`, tomorrow `ninja` or `msbuild` and CMake handles it with simple `cmake --build` which you can put in a script or readme.

But since the inception of [presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) these 2 methods started to really diverge. You can add some things in the build part of your preset which then can be invoked by `cmake --build --preset MyPreset` while you can't do the same with simple `make`.

So since you are using CMake as your project tool I'd recommend to start using its interface for the build since that's how it will be meant to use in the future anyway (at least it seems so).

Answer (score 0):

`make` is not a recognized command in Windows. In times like this, `cmake --build .` is your friend.

`cmake build .` also works, sometimes and I don't know the deeper explanations of these phenomena.

Answer (score -1):

cmake -B ...typehere

type - build type
e.g .sln projects for vs studio

make - build your project

cmake - allows you to create a different build types for your project.